# Dynamic Inventory script output vs JSON file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm writing a dynamic inventory script which queries Docker containers. It outputs JSON, which I can save to a file and use, but I get parse errors from Ansible when I try to use the script directly.

```
[root@297b1ca0cfa4 /]# docker-dynamic-inventory > inv.json
[root@297b1ca0cfa4 /]# cat inv.json 
{"all": {"hosts": {"inv_clyde_1": null, "inv_blinky_1": null, "inv_inky_1": null, "inv_pinky_1": null, "admiring_chandrasekhar": null}, "_meta": {"hostvars": {}}, "vars": {"ansible_connection": "docker"}}}

[root@297b1ca0cfa4 /]# ansible all -i inv.json -m ping
inv_clyde_1 | FAILED! => {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "docker command not found in PATH"
}
```

Note that I don't care if the ping fails, getting that far means that my inventory works. Ansible is successfully interpreting the JSON and the inventory it represents. Now compare this with using the script directly:

```
[root@297b1ca0cfa4 /]# ansible all -i /usr/bin/docker-dynamic-inventory -m ping
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /usr/bin/docker-dynamic-inventory with script plugin: 
You defined a group 'all' with bad data for the host list:  
{u'hosts': {u'inv_clyde_1': None, u'inv_inky_1': None,
 u'admiring_chandrasekhar': None, u'inv_pinky_1': None, u'inv_blinky_1': None}, 
u'_meta': {u'hostvars': {}}, u'vars': {u'ansible_connection': u'docker'}}
```

[Ansible's docs on Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups) show it using a dictionary and null values to represent hosts, which is why I do that here.

Apart from the fact that Ansible prints the dict it read in from JSON, I'm not seeing what's different/wrong here. Why does the stored JSON output work where the script won't?

Comment: "*[Ansible's docs on Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups) show it using a dictionary and null values to represent hosts*" ー that's not true, read it carefully.

Comment: @techraf Yes it is. If you go the Hosts and Groups section, you'll see that all the hosts shown in the YAML example are keys with null values. That's one of the ways YAML handles null. You could also write `null` in there.

Also, I'd appreciate it if you would point out what you mean instead of leaving a cryptic and condescending comment.

Comment: No, they are not. Read it carefully: under `all:` you see `hosts:` under which you see **a single element (`mail.example.com`) list of strings**.

Comment: And right below that, all the children have `hosts` which are keys with null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out `all` is a special group, but only when interpreted with the script parser. In a static inventory, all can be a **dictionary of keys with null values**, but when coming from a script, the `host` value for `all` must be a **list of strings**.

```
{"all": 
  {"hosts": ["admiring_chandrasekhar", "inv_inky_1", "inv_pinky_1", 
             "inv_blinky_1", "inv_clyde_1"], 
   "_meta": {"hostvars": {}}, 
   "vars": {"ansible_connection": "docker"}}}
```